# Get new position of element after Mootools Drag completes

Tags: javascript, mootools, draggable

I want to get the value of the left positioning or margin-left or something that shows how far left the div element has been dragged. I don’t know howto access it. Trying to get 'left' just shows auto.

http://jsfiddle.net/nicekiwi/ZzwNt/1/

Is it even possible?

Say I drag the image 20px to the right, I want the alert box in onComplete to return the value of 20. Hope you get the idea.

I've tried using el.getComputedSize.computedLeft, but it just returns 0.

Mootools 1.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [getScroll()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions#Element%3agetScroll) function is what you're looking for, as this returns the amount that your containing div has been scrolled from top left.

```
onComplete: function(el){
    var imgPosition = el.getScroll();
    console.log(imgPosition.x);
    console.log(imgPosition.y);
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle as an example - http://jsfiddle.net/ZzwNt/2/

Hope this helps.